# Arrange base plots and grid.tables on the same page

Tags: r, pdf, r-grid

I have 2 plots (created using Base graphics) and 2 data frames that I would like to combine onto one sheet in a PDF. I'm using grid.table to create a tableGrobs from my data frames. I'm having a lot of difficulty formatting the PDF output. In particular, I've been unsuccessful keeping all the objects on the same page. I want the right pannel to contain one graph, and the left panel to contain the other graph, and 2 tables below (landscape format).

Currently my code is something like the following:

```
library('gridExtra')

pdf("Rplots.pdf", paper = "USr", height = 8.5, width = 11)

layout(matrix(c(1,3, 2,3, 4,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

plot(myPlot1)    
grid.table(df1)    
plot(myPlot2)
grid.table(df2)

dev.off()
```

I **do not** want to use ggplot2.

Comment: Have you had a look at `gridBase`, to combine base and grid plots

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381404/how-to-create-a-pdf-in-r-with-tables-and-plots 
Can someone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To combine `base` plots and `grid` objects the package `gridBase` is useful.

A rough worked example base on your layout above

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)
library(gridExtra)


layout(matrix(c(1,3, 2,3, 4,3), nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

# First base plot
plot(1:10)

# second base plot 
frame()
# Grid regions of current base plot (ie from frame)
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)
# Table grob
grob <-  tableGrob(iris[1:2,1:2])  
grid.draw(grob)

popViewport(3)

# third base plot
plot(1:10)

# fourth
frame()
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)  
grid.draw(grob)
popViewport(3)
```

Which gives

[image]

Comment: I would like to do the same, but with 1 plot and one table. but i get an error when i run `layout(matrix(c(1,3), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))`. `Error in layout(matrix(c(1, 3), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)) : 
  layout matrix must contain at least one reference
to each of the values {1 ... 3}`

Comment: @Quant, You have to say the positions of each  the plots that you reference with the numbers in layout, from min to max. You only have 1 and 3 but no 2 ( as the error says; but not too clearly. So use c(1,2).