# Venn diagrams in multiple figure

Tags: r, venn-diagram

is there a way to have the following venn diagrams as a 3rd figure after the two histograms below??
I'd like to have the two venn diagram one on top of the other

```
library(VennDiagram)

plus.venn<-draw.pairwise.venn(368, 1171, 149) #venn diagram 1

minus.venn<-draw.pairwise.venn(349, 1335, 173) #venn diagram 2

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

a<-sample(1:10000,3000)

b<-sample(5000:15000,3000)

hist(a)

hist(b)
```

Comment: `draw.pariwise.venn` seems to use `grid` graphics while `hist` uses base graphics. It's not fun to mix the two. Can you create a grid-friendly histogram with `ggplot2` or `lattice` instead?

Comment: OK... In fact I am not actually sure which is the best way to achieve this...

Comment: if you want to combine the venndaigram (grid graphics) and hist plots (base graphics) you can using the package `gridBase` (an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192838/how-to-arrange-base-plots-and-grid-tables-on-the-same-page)). but you will likely get nicer plots if you follow MrFlicks advice by doing all oyur plots in grid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expand upon MrFlicks and my comments above.

You can combine base and grid graphics using the `gridBase` package. However, if you are not constrained to use base R graphics you may find it easier to produce all your plots using a grid based graphics package and combine them using the `gridExtra` package.

Your data

```
library(VennDiagram)

plus.venn <- draw.pairwise.venn(368, 1171, 149) #venn diagram 1
minus.venn <-draw.pairwise.venn(349, 1335, 173) #venn diagram 2
a <-sample(1:10000,3000)
b <-sample(5000:15000,3000)
```

Arranging base and grid plots

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

# Layout of plots - 4 plots of equal size
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, byrow = TRUE))

# First & second base plot
hist(a)
hist(b)

# Grid regions of current base plot (ie from frame)
frame()
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)
grid.draw(plus.venn)
popViewport(3)

# fourth
frame()
vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)  
grid.draw(minus.venn)
popViewport(3)
```

Which produces

[image]

Or using `ggplot2` to produce your histograms and combining using `grid.arrange`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(qplot(a, geom="histogram") + theme_classic(),
             qplot(b, geom="histogram") + theme_classic(),
             grobTree(plus.venn),
             grobTree(minus.venn),
             ncol=2)
```

Which produces

[image]

You can change the layout of either method to what you want.