# How to put many vennplots in one slide/plot

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have five venndigram plots and I want put them in one slide. I wonder anyone could help me how to do it. I used the the following code but could not help me.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = list(VD1, VD2, VD3, VD4, VD5),
                        ncol = 3, nrow = 2, labels = LETTERS[1:5])
```

These were the errors

```
Error in gList(list(1, wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
 2: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
 3: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
 4: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
 5: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list
```

Thank you!

Comment: How were the venndigrams created? You need to provide the package and function you use.

Comment: @Darren Tsai, Thank you. The package I used is ***VennDiagram*** and the function was ***venn.diagram***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Venn diagrams in multiple figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269538/venn-diagrams-in-multiple-figure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid.arrange` in combination with `gTree` like this:

```r
library(VennDiagram)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: futile.logger
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(1)
list1 <- list(A=sample(LETTERS, 12), B=sample(LETTERS, 12))
venn1 <- venn.diagram(list1, filename = NULL)
set.seed(2)
list2 <- list(A=sample(LETTERS, 16), B=sample(LETTERS, 12))
venn2 <- venn.diagram(list2, filename = NULL)

venn3 <- venn.diagram(list(C=sample(LETTERS, 16), D=sample(LETTERS, 12)), filename = NULL)
venn4 <- venn.diagram(list(E=sample(LETTERS, 20), F=sample(LETTERS, 22)), filename = NULL)
venn5 <- venn.diagram(list(G=sample(LETTERS, 13), H=sample(LETTERS, 14)), filename = NULL)
grid.arrange(gTree(children=venn1),
             gTree(children=venn2),
             gTree(children=venn3),
             gTree(children=venn4),
             gTree(children=venn5),
             ncol=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>(https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)

Comment: Hi, @user12728748,  Do you think this can be reproducible if I want to do the trivalent Venn diagram? I got something wired. It plots the three-circles for each case but couldn't show me the intersection region despite the presence of some overlapping values. One more thing, how I can label each as A,B,C.....?

Comment: If you mean by trivalent a list of 3 vectors, it works the same way (e.g. `list(A=sample(LETTERS, 12), B=sample(LETTERS, 12), C=sample(LETTERS, 20))`). If by label you mean adding a title, just add `main="Venn A"` or something like that to the venn.diagram function...