# R grid.table - table keeps plotting on top of other plots

Tags: r, graph, r-grid

I'm trying to use grid.table for the first time.
The tables keep plotting on top of what ever is in the plotting window. In other words, it does not create a new Plot display, it just added it onto what ever is there already.
Is there a way to force it to use a new plotting window?

```
library(grid)
d <- head(iris[,1:3])
plot(d)
grid.table(d)
```

[image]library(gridExtra)

Comment: They're using different graphics systems: "base graphics" vs "grid graphics"  Pat Murrell (the developer of grid) has some good explanations.

Comment: Here's a good example of combining the two systems in the same graphic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192838/arrange-base-plots-and-grid-tables-on-the-same-page

Comment: this is actually the opposite of what I was trying to do, but it's also the next thing I was going to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use grid.newpage() to get a new page in your panel.

```
library(grid)
d <- head(iris[,1:3])
plot(d)
library(gridExtra)

grid.newpage()

grid.table(d)
```

Comment: this is amazing! I've looked in so many posts where people are trying to delete just the current plot without deleting all of them in RStudio. Eveyone keeps saying it's not posible and here it is!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helps!