# 1 plot and 1 table per pdf page using base r?

Tags: r, plot, layout

I have a loop running for 50 patients. In it, I produce `plot_i` and `table_i`. I need `plot_1` and `table_1` on page 1 of a pdf, `plot_2` and `table_2` on page 2, etc. The plot is produced using base r, not `ggplot2`, so `grid.arrange` does not work. When I try to use `par` and `layout`, it only picks up on the plots, not tables. How do I specify to `layout`/`par` that I need the plot AND the table, or is there another function that would work?

I tried using layout/par but it just picks out two plots for each page, and ignores the tables. I want something that does what `grid.arrange(plot_i, table_i)` would do.

Comment: How are your tables produced? Are you using the `pdf()` function or an Rmarkdown document or something else? If you could share some sample data and code for, say, 2 simple example plots and 2 tables that would give us something to work with as well as help us understand what you're actually doing.

Comment: The tables are produced using tableGrob and I'm using the pdf() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using some manipulations to the layout, and extending the use of some of the techniques found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192838/arrange-base-plots-and-grid-tables-on-the-same-page) using `grid`, `gridExtra`, and `gridBase`:

Example Data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(patient = rep(1:5, each = 10),
                 var1 = runif(50),
                 var2 = rnbinom(50, mu = 1, size = 0.25))
```

Code

```
pdf("example.pdf")
for(i in unique(df$patient)){
  dta <- df[df$patient == i, ]
  tab <- table(dta$var1, dta$var2)
  
  layout(matrix(1:2, nrow = 1))
  plot(dta$var1, dta$var2, main = paste0("Patient ", i))
  frame()
  vps <- gridBase::baseViewports()
  grid::pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)
  grid::grid.draw(gridExtra::tableGrob(tab))
}
dev.off()
```

This will put a figure and table side by side on the plot and each individual patient will have be on their own page. You can play around with the layout/margins/positioning as needed for your real data. Good luck!
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get it to work. I get the error: Error in dim(data) <- dim :  dims [product 20] do not match the length of object [12]. Any idea why?

Comment: Unfortunately I wont be able to provide much additional help without a a reproducible example